# How do I Switch single quotes to double single quotes on output from T-SQL SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to script the creation of the INSERT SQL for data in a table. (similar to the SQL Server built in scripts)

```
DECLARE @HEADER varchar(255)

SET @HEADER = 'insert into Table ( Column1 , Column2)
values ( N'''

SELECT 
@Header + Column1 + ''', N''' + Column2 + ''')'
+ CHAR(10)
FROM Table
ORDER BY Column1
```

In Column1 I have text that contains single quotes and I need it to come out as double single quoted text like it does when using "Generate scripts" directly from SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function to double up your quotes, and you'll need to wrap the resulting string in quotes.  Note that this works for `NOT NULL` columns, so tweak it if you need to support nullable columns.

```
SELECT
  'INSERT INTO Table (Column1, Column2) VALUES (N''' +
     REPLACE(Column1, '''', '''''') + ''', N''' +
     REPLACE(Column2, '''', '''''') + ''')'
FROM Table
ORDER BY Column1
```

Comment: QuoteName would work for me BUT
Column1 = nvarchar(2000) and QUOTENAME is limited to nvarchar(258)

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the clarification.  Check out the revised solution using `REPLACE`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function.

```
SELECT 
@Header + QUOTENAME(Column1) + ''', N''' + Column2 + ''')'
+ CHAR(10)
FROM Table
ORDER BY Column1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to generate an insert script based on an existing table?

I would recommend you download [SSMS Tools](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Features). It's a great add in with additional features for use with SSMS.  One of these features allows you to right click a table and it will generate an insert script for you that contains the data within the table.

Comment: SSMS works great but I need to post process the output significantly to match a clients format I am attempting to recreate the SSMS output in a way that I don't end up doing global replaces on the generated script.

Like it all has to have lowercase for the SQL, I need to add the line break prior to the insert, the defaulted brackets around the column names need to be removed etc...